# GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM never returns negative

Tags: c++, winapi

I am only seeing positive numbers returned from GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM, even when it should be negative as I roll the mouse wheel towards me.

```
case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
            short wheel_delta = 0;
            wheel_delta = GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(Addtl_Info_L);
```

Also, this page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646254%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indicates rolling the wheel forward gives a positive number and backwards a negative whereas this page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indicates it is left and right rather than forwards and backwards.

Here is the full message handler:

```
            LRESULT CALLBACK Message_Handler(HWND App_Handle, UINT Message_Type, WPARAM Addtl_Info_W, LPARAM Addtl_Info_L) {
                short wheel_delta(0);
                switch(Message_Type) {
                case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
                    wheel_delta = GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(Addtl_Info_L);
                    if (wheel_delta > 0) {
                        std::wostringstream outs;  
                        outs << "Wheel delta is positive" << std::endl;
                        OutputDebugString(outs.str().c_str());
                        graphics_manager.camera_tilt = graphics_manager.camera_tilt + 0.1f;
                    } else if (wheel_delta < 0) {
                        std::wostringstream outs;  
                        outs << "Wheel delta is negative" << std::endl;
                        OutputDebugString(outs.str().c_str());
                        graphics_manager.camera_tilt = graphics_manager.camera_tilt - 0.1f;
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
                return DefWindowProc(App_Handle, Message_Type, Addtl_Info_W, Addtl_Info_L);
            }
```

Comment: @chris, `GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM()` extracts the high-order word itself, you do not have to apply `HIWORD()` beforehand.

Comment: Can you show what `Addtl_Info_L` is and how it is initialized?

Comment: Try `wheel_delta = HIWORD(Addtl_Info_L)` to see if that gives different results. I'm assuming `Addtl_Info_L` is from WndProc's function arguments, typically labeled `wParam`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the `LPARAM` to `GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM`.  You should be passing the `WPARAM` (`Addtl_Info_W`, not `Addtl_Info_L`).

Answer (score 1):

You should show your whole message loop, or at least where "Addtl_Info_L" is defined, because it should be the wParam "win32msg->wParam".

```
#define GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam) ((short)HIWORD(wParam))
```

Perhaps your converting the short value to an unsigned int or outputting the short value using an unsigned format string in your tests? You could check for a negative using a conditional to make sure.

```
if(wheel_delta < 0) { /* do something */ }
```